# glVertexAttribPointer raising GL_INVALID_OPERATION on OpenGL 3.2 on OS X

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

`glVertexAttribPointer` is raising `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on my OpenGL 3.2 program running in Cocoa for OS X 10.8.3.

I've setup a vao using `APPLE` functions, and pulled down attribute locations using `glGetAttribLocation`.

Despite binding the vao, vbo, and enabling the attribute, its resulting in the invalid operation.

I can successfully modify the clear color, and am not concerned with the integrity of the GL context.

For the header I have these defined:

```
GLuint _vao;
GLuint _vbo;
```

You can also assume here that `positionAttribute` is an opaque object with a reference to a `vec3`.

In the implementation, I'm running this:

```
glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &_vao);
glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(_vao);

static GLfloat vertices[] = {
    0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
    1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
    0.f, 1.f, 0.f,
    1.f, 1.f, 0.f
};

glGenBuffers(1, &_vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute.location);

glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute.location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

// Error here
```

Has anyone else experienced this or may know what's causing this?

Comment: VAOs have been core since 3.0, why are you using the extension entrypoints?

Comment: Can you test the value returned by `glGetAttribLocation`? Specifically, that it's not `(-1)`?

Comment: @genpfault Honestly, I had started using the OSXGLEssentials, which had used APPLE's extension. After removing the extension (and finding the proper header file), the error went away.

Comment: @BrettHale I did, and it does return a valid value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer and thanks goes to [genpfault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44729/genpfault) for pointing out the obvious.

I had missed an `#else` block in a referenced conditional `#define` that would use the `APPLE` extension in pre-3 OpenGL.

The solution is to remove the `APPLE` extension and use native OpenGL.

- `glGenVertexArrays`
- `glBindVertexArrays`